# how best to use phplist to avoid getting emails marked spam

Tags: php, email, list, phplist

I am thinking of using phplist to manage newsletter and other types of subscriptions. but i guess there is a limit applied by ISP on how much email i can send..

Any tips and tricks around how to use phplist and have a professional mass mailing software running

Comment: You might want to try asking this on serverfault.com, but I am not sure if phplist is more programming- or server-related.

Comment: most of the mails from php list goes to spam

Answer (score 0):

First things first - check with your Hosting Provider to find out whether there are any limits and what they are. It's always easier to obey rules when you know what they are.

Regarding obeying those rules (or just trying to obey any rules you are advised of), refer to the PHPList Documentation section "[Setting the Send Speed (Rate)](http://docs.phplist.com/PhpListConfigSendRate)".